# When is it appropriate to use 'admixture' rather than 'mixture'?

Tags: word-choice

I saw the word **admixture** used in a sentence recently and looked it up in the Paperback Oxford English Dictionary only to find that its definition is "a mixture".

This is the sentence:

> The 'Natura' section features a series of sixteen prose poems,
>   redolent in many ways of Hill's *Mercian Hymns* in their admixtures of
>   natural and urban landscape, dramatised autobiography and historical
>   reference, fomal and colloquial styles.

Why is "admixtures" used here rather than "mixture"?

Comment: I don't think your example turns on the distinction between ***mixture*** and ***admixture*** at all - it's just the kind of pretentious writing that's all too common in Lit Crit contexts. And I must say I find this particular use of ***redolent*** equally inappropriate. If the writer really wanted a 50-cent word there, ***reminiscent*** would be better - the target of "redolent" is more usually something which is *directly* perceived through the senses (particularly, obviously, *olfactory*), rather than just another indirection through "evocative" music/poetry/artwork.

Comment: *Admixture* is rare compared to *mixture*; I would personally never use it, even in formal writing.  To my ear it carries a connotation similar to *adulterated*, i.e. "some elements of the overall mixture shouldn't have been added", but I don't think that is what was meant in this quote.

Comment: @FumbleFingers (dropping the sledgehammer)

Comment: @tylerharms: As a "Literary Studies" graduate myself, I'm sure I've been as guilty as the next man of this sort of thing. And doubtless once in a blue moon an obscure word choice really *does* carry some subtle significance that passes me by. But I suspect ***admixture*** here is just a somewhat clumsy way of trying to emphasise the *judicious, artistic* "mixing" - pluralised to add even *more* emphasis through "unusual word choice". Most likely because the writer didn't actually think of the far more precise term ***juxtaposition***.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Admixture** is a minor ingredient, a smaller part of mixture, added to mixture

**Mixture** is irrelevant of ingredients proportions, and is one whole mixture.

In your quote, the author wants to stress that every single component that was added, plays its role in the final impression. To make such an emphasis, 'admixture' works better.

Technical example from [Federal Highway Administration](http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/infrastructure/materialsgrp/admixture.html):
(I am giving a technical context because in this case 'admixture' is the only acceptable term, and is absolutely different from 'mixture')

> Chemical Admixtures
>
> Chemical admixtures are added to concrete in very small amounts mainly
>   for the entrainment of air, reduction of water or cement content,
>   plasticization of fresh concrete mixtures, or control of setting time.
>
> Seven types of chemical admixtures are specified in ASTM C 494, and
>   AASHTO M 194, depending on their purpose or purposes in PCC. Air
>   entraining admixtures are specified in ASTM C 260 and AASHTO M 154.
>   General and physical requirements for each type of admixture are
>   included in the specifications.

**Examples**

[An article on Yourdictionary.com](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/admixture) packed with lots of other context examples (follow the link).

Most dictionaries do not explain the difference, I found only two that mention that admixture as 'a minor ingredient':

**The Oxford Pocket Dictionary of Current English (2009)**

> ad·mix·ture / adˈmikschər/ something mixed with something else,
>
> - typically is a minor ingredient.
> - the action of adding such an ingredient.

[Collins dictionary article](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/admixture?showCookiePolicy=true) is good for giving synonyms and clearly splits admixture in two meanings, '**mixture**' and '**component**':

> **admixture**
>
> noun
>
> - mixture, combination, compound, blend, fusion, alloy, medley, amalgamation, meld, intermixture
>
>   - His heart beat with an admixture of aversion and thrill.
> - ingredient, element, component, constituent

**Example from the question:** (mixture or admixture)

> The 'Natura' section features a series of sixteen prose poems,
>   redolent in many ways of Hill's Mercian Hymns in their admixtures of
>   natural and urban landscape, dramatised autobiography and historical
>   reference, fomal and colloquial styles.

In this case replacing 'admixtures' with 'mixtures' would not be a grammar mistake but it would shift the emphases. The author refers to different components of the Mercian Hymns, and enumerates them. But, if 'mixtures' were used, the emphasis would shift towards hymns themselves rather than components. The description would become less poetic.

Comment: This is a great, clear, and direct answer. +1. Would you mind editing in some references to dictionaries?

Comment: Could you give an example sentence of its appropriate use? I don't follow your explanation.

Comment: @Dan Bron - That's done, thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @camden_kid  Examples added

Comment: @javaNoobs Would it be incorrect to use the word 'mixture' in the sentence in my question? If so, does that mean 'admixture' is not used correctly in that sentence? I guess this is what is confusing me.

Comment: @camden_kid The answer is edited. Both 'mixture' and 'admixture' is a correct grammar but the meaning would slightly differ, see the answer edited.

Comment: @javaNoobs It's the prose poems being referred to, not the Hymns. This would be the case with 'admixtures' and 'mixture'.

Comment: @camden_kid Anyway, prose poems inherit the properties of hymns in this sentence because they are redolent (similar).

Answer (score 9):

The point is about **adding to mixture elements that are *alien* to some extent to the majority or to each other**. As you can see, that collection of poems is a bit strange in their eclecticness:-). See the last example in the dictionary definition.

Let me give you the official separation first as per the mother of all synonym dictionaries:

> *Admixture* adds to *mixture* **the suggestion of the alien character of one or more of the constituent elements**
>
> [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms: A Dictionary of
>   Discriminated ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA542)

Then, lemme give you the whole/real shebang of a definition :-)

> **ad·mix·ture**
>
> noun
>
> 1 a :  the act of mixing
>
> *a favorable result will be obtained only by careful admixture of ingredients*
>
> b :  the fact of being mixed
>
> *repeated sifting is necessary to secure complete admixture*
>
> 2 a :  an element or substance added by mixing
>
> *comic verses with an occasional admixture of mild bawdry — Alexander Cowie*
>
> b :  a substance other than cement, aggregate, or water that is mixed
>   with concrete
>
> 3 :  a product of mixing:
>
> a :  a compound formed by mixing
>
> *by using wool, silk, cotton, and linen fibers in various admixtures — A. C. Morrison*
>
> b :  something formed by combining two or more things
>
> *The presiding spirit of this place—**an admixture of fear and what passes for hope** among chronic gamblers—can be found in the basement
>   beneath the grandstand … — David Samuels, Harper’s, February 1999*
>
> **Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary**

Answer (score 3):

Affirming and expanding upon the good answer of javaNoobs:

1. *[Mixture](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mixture)* is a more general term with broader application than *admixture*:

> noun
>
> 1.0 A substance made by mixing other substances together:
>   *form the mixture into a manageable dough*
>
> 1.1 [MASS NOUN] The process of mixing or being mixed.
>
> 1.2 A combination of different things in which the component elements are individually distinct:
>   *the old town is a mixture of narrow medieval streets and 18th-century architecture*
>
> 1.3 Chemistry The product of the random distribution of one substance through another without any chemical reaction, as distinct from a compound.
>
> 1.4 The charge of gas or vapour mixed with air which is admitted to the cylinder of an internal-combustion engine, especially as regards
>   the ratio of fuel to air:

---

2. *[Admixture](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/admixture)* shares some of the definitions of *mixture*, and in may cases is an acceptable *[synonym](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/mixture?s=ts)*:

> noun
>
> 1.0 A mixture:
>   *he felt that his work was an admixture of aggression and creativity*
>
> [Entry 1.1 omitted for consideration below]
>
> 1.2 [MASS NOUN] The action of adding an ingredient to something else.

---

3. Entry 1.1 in the ODO is unique to *[admixture](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/admixture)*:

> 1.1 Something mixed with something else:
>   *green with an admixture of black*

The prefix [*ad*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ad-) carries [*admixture*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=admixture&allowed_in_frame=0) **toward** the definition of *[additive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/additive)* in some contexts:

> noun
>
> A substance added to something in small quantities to improve or
>   preserve it:

***Mixture* is not generally used to describe an added ingredient in that way.**

---

www.oxforddictionaries.com
thesaurus.com
www.etymonline.com

Answer (score 0):

You guys (all people regardless of gender) are much more intelligent than I am but I think I can help from reading this word in context a variety of times.

The word admixture is different than either "lesser ingredient" or "mixture" but more like "lesser mixture" when referring to the "entire mixture".  It is more like a sub-level mixture regarding a whole mixture.

Like in genealogy and culture, YOU are the mixture we are talking about and your parents, grandparents, etc are all the admixtures that YOU are comprised of.

Such as if we were talking about YOUR MOM (that's right I brought moms into this) then she would be the mixture and your grandparents, etc would all be her admixtures.

The word admixture is literally used to refer to the ADDED MIXTURES that comprise the END RESULT MIXTURE.

Don't compare this with individual ingredients.  An ingredient is singular in nature (ie salt or sugar) but combining salt & sugar together creates a mixture.  Thus, adding the mixture of salt & sugar to another mixture creates a new mixture with sub-level mixtures being the components aka admixtures.

So in reference to the above excerpt it is referring to mixing several independent mixtures of cultures & atmospheres to create a brand new mixed culture & atmosphere.

I would argue that the word admixture will ONLY work here and is being used properly.  And the word mixture absolutely does not work here.  Because the focus is on the individual mixtures that create the whole mixture while retaining the reference to the topic of the whole mixture.

Thats my take on it anyways